# When is a GKGameCenterViewController released?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

The following documentation has the sample code below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW9

> Listing 4-9  Displaying the leaderboard page of the Game Center user
>   interface

```
- (void) showLeaderboard: (NSString*) leaderboardID
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
       gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
       gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
       gameCenterController.leaderboardTimeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
       gameCenterController.leaderboardCategory = leaderboardID;
       [self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

When do you call "release" on the GKGameCenterViewController ? Should it be only after the view controller is dismissed, or can you call it at the end of this method ? Or should one just call autorelease ?

Answer (score 0):

The project uses Automatic Reference Counting, therefore you do not need to explicitly declare release or dealloc. For reference, it is deallocated after the view leaves the view hierarchy.

Comment: My project does not use arc. Does that mean I should just use autorelease ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with non-arc projects, sorry. Since arc is now the standard, you can use -fobjc-arc to directly use arc in a non-arc project. Similarly, you can use -fno-objc-arc to use non-arc in an arc project. Just add it per file as a flag in the compile sources build phase.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation to back this up (because all of Apple's documentation now assumes ARC), but my recollection from the pre-ARC days is that you release a modal view controller once you present it. I'm reasonably sure the presenting view controller will take a strong reference to the presented view controller.  So:

```
- (void) showLeaderboard: (NSString*) leaderboardID
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
       gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
       gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
       gameCenterController.leaderboardTimeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
       gameCenterController.leaderboardCategory = leaderboardID;
       [self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
       [gameCenterController release];
    }
}
```

A better answer might be, "use ARC". :)  Seriously, ARC rules.

Comment: won't autorelease be safer then ? Or is it unnecessary ?

Comment: In this case, nope, autorelease isn't necessary.

Comment: no no - i mean instead of using release, use autorelease, so it is released only when the pool is released.

Comment: Nope, no need to use autorelease, as opposed to release. I mean, it won't *hurt* - it just delays the release until the next trip through the runloop. But regular release is all that's needed.